# Creating a Gmail filter to delete all emails sent to that Gmail address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, domain

I need to write a Gmail filter that deletes any email that comes into my Gmail inbox addressed to that Gmail address. I need to make an exception for responses that come from accepting or declining a calendar invitation.

This is what I have so far (I'm using an example Gmail address and domain, hence the use of `.invalid`):

```
Matches: {to:richard.surname@gmail.invalid to:richardsurname@gmail.invalid} -from:google -filename:ics -filename:vcs
Do this: Delete it
```

Is there a better way to do this?

### Further information / Rationale

I own my own domain (`richard.invalid`) which has a number of email aliases set up. One of them (`me@richard.invalid`) points to my Gmail address (`richard.surname@gmail.invalid`). When I reply to any email, I have [Gmail configured](https://www.thedigitalnonprofit.com/blog/use-gmail-own-domain-free) so that it sends emails from `me@richard.invalid`.

This works great.

However there are at least 10 people in the world who blindly give out `richard.surname@gmail.invalid` or `richardsurname@gmail.invalid` as their own email address even though they don't actually have access to it. After years of responding to emails and trying to educate those individuals, I've given up and would like to delete anything sent to those addresses.

The only issue I have is that Google Calendar always sends invitations from my Gmail address, so I need to add an exception to my filter to ensure that responses to those aren't accidentally deleted. This isn't ideal, but I only ever send invitations to my other half.

As I've owned the domain for many years, I never send any emails from `richard.surname@gmail.invalid` - so I don't expect any legitimate email to ever go to it.

I'm using the free version of Gmail, not GSuite.